# How to prevent ModelSIM from stopping during simulation?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

I'm trying to simulate a down counter which I described using D-Latches in SystemVerilog but when I start simulating, ModelSIM stops working and I can not do anything.

This is the down counter description

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module Down_Counter_Part5 (input RST,CLK,EnableIN, output[7:0] Qout, output EnableOUT);

    genvar i;
    wire[8:0] En;
    wire[7:0] D,Qbar;

    assign En[0] = EnableIN;
    assign EnableOUT = En[8];

    generate
        for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
            assign D[i] = (Qout[i] ^ En[i]) & (~RST);
            assign En[i+1] = Qbar[i] & En[i];
            Clocked_D_Latch Ii (D[i],CLK,Qout[i],Qbar[i]);
        end
    endgenerate

endmodule
```

And It's my testbench

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module Testbench_Part6 ();

    logic rst = 1,clk = 1,enablein = 1;
    wire[7:0] qout;
    wire enableout;

    Down_Counter_Part5 UUT (rst,clk,enablein,qout,enableout);

    initial repeat (5) #5000 rst = ~rst;

endmodule
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Isn't it the clk signal you want to toggle?

Comment: it stops at 0ns and nothing happens then

Comment: Yes I want to toggle clk but none of them work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a zero-time infinite combinational feedback loop. This will cans the simulator to timeout or appear to hag.

I'm assuming the latch is transparent when `CLK` is high; you didn't show that bit of code. Therefore `Qout` will equal `D` when CLK is high. But when `En` is high, then `D` will be equal the the invert of `Qout`. Since there is not time blocking, `Qout` will be reevaluated, causing another update to `D`, causing another update to `Qout`, and on and on forever.

If you are only going to simulate this, then add a little delay to the assignment so you can see the feedback loop in wavefrom/logfile. I would also suggest starting `RST` as 0 so the X and Z values can be flushed out.

```
assign #1 D[i] = (Qout[i] ^ En[i]) & (~RST);
```

Adding the `#1` is not a proper solution for real design. A proper solution requires the all signals to be in a determinable at each time step without `#` delays.